# StackOverflow Notifications in Visual Studio 2010 Extension

Tags: app

[image]

**About**

VSCommands 2010 Lite is a free extension for Visual Studio 2010 which now includes StackOverflow Notifications in a form of a toolbar button which periodically checks SO for new badges, messages and reputation changes.

Once extension is installed in Visual Studio 2010 go to Tools->Options->VSCommands 2010->Other Settings where you can enter your user id and specify the period for which notfications should be checked (Today, Last Two Days, This Week, This Month).

[image]

**License**

VSCommands Lite is free to use.

**Download**

[VSCommands 2010 in Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf)

**Platform**

Visual Studio 2010 extension

**Contact**

http://vscommands.uservoice.com/

**Code**

Visual Studio 2010 SDK + [Stacky](http://stacky.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I don't think the link provided is correct. It takes me to VSCommands 2010.

Comment: You should add some details on how to actually point this extension at your SO account.

Comment: @George: this is part of VSCommands 2010 extension
@Kevin: thanks for suggestion, just updated config info.

Comment: @jarek: Oh, okay. My bad.

Comment: me thinks that stalking yourself while writing code is, ummm... an interesting concept ;-)

Comment: what are the chances of getting this for VS 2008?

Comment: @Travis, sorry but there will be no VS2008 version in the nearest future.

Comment: is this app broken?  Toolbar button only says StackOverflow...